# Сокращение, ограничение, снижение

Tags: лексика, синонимы

Сокращение, ограничение, снижение поголовья. Сокращение, ограничение, снижение посевных площадей.

Ответьте, пожалуйста, будут ли эти процессы в данных случаях синонимами? И возможно ли употребление всех этих сочетаний?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полных синонимов не бывает, а употребление зависит от контекста. **Ограничение** отличается от двух других слов тем, что может использоваться главным образом при ссылке на **внешнее действие**, *ограничивающее* поголовье скота (кто-то распорядился его *ограничить*), в то время как **сокращение** или **снижение** (более близкие один к другому синонимы) может происходить по любым причинам; эти слова могу характеризовать статистические данные (поголовье *сократилось, снизилось, уменьшилось*), а не только чьи-то действия (принятие мер к снижению, к сокращению).